# WPF Tooltip Image in Datagrid Column

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I need to have a datagrid column with some image, and for each cell I need to see, in the tooltip, the bigger image.
The datagrid is binded on a ObsevarbleCollection of MyOBjects, and MyImage and MyBigImage are poperties of MyObject.
With XAML here there is the working code:

```
<c1:C1DataGrid.Columns>
            <c1:DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <c1:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Image Source="{Binding MyImage}" >
                            <Image.ToolTip>
                                <ToolTip >
                                    <StackPanel>
                                        <Image Source="{Binding MyBigImage}" />
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </ToolTip>
                            </Image.ToolTip>
                        </Image>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </c1:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </c1:DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </c1:C1DataGrid.Columns>
```

But I need to move the code in the c# side.
So I've tried this code:

```
C1.WPF.DataGrid.DataGridTemplateColumn col1 = new 
C1.WPF.DataGrid.DataGridTemplateColumn();

FrameworkElementFactory factoryImg = new 
FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(Image));

Binding b1 = new Binding("MyImage");
b1.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
factoryImg.SetValue(Image.SourceProperty, b1);
DataTemplate ttTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(StackPanel));          

FrameworkElementFactory spFactory = new 
FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(StackPanel));
spFactory.SetValue(StackPanel.OrientationProperty, Orientation.Horizontal);
FrameworkElementFactory imgHolder = new 
FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(Image));
Binding b2 = new Binding("MyBigImage");
b2.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
imgHolder.SetBinding(Image.SourceProperty, b2);
spFactory.AppendChild(imgHolder);
ttTemplate.VisualTree = spFactory;
ToolTip tt = new System.Windows.Controls.ToolTip();
tt.ContentTemplate = ttTemplate;
factoryImg.SetValue(TextBlock.ToolTipProperty, tt);
DataTemplate cellTemplate1 = new DataTemplate();
cellTemplate1.VisualTree = factoryImg;
col1.CellTemplate = cellTemplate1;
MyDataGrid.Columns.Add(col1);
cellTemplate1.Seal();
```

With this code the image in the cell appears correctly, but the tooltip on the image is an empty panel, no image is visualized.
If I create a new BitmapImage the tooltip works, so I think it is a binding problem.
What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Ok solved, I've forgot to set the DataContext property:

imgHolder.SetValue(TextBlock.DataContextProperty, *List*);